# Is it possible to dynamically change namespace to ServiceContract during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

ex:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "@services.url@/",
        Name = "FedExContract")]
```

I need to change the value of "@services.url@" during runtime.

Comment: why do you **need** to change the namespace during runtime?

Comment: This is to support some of the existing processes.  My client is using Eclipse to publish the services to IIS and they replace these tags during build time.  I am planning to port all these values to database instead of build process.

Comment: I can't imagine that this is possible, I mean pratically how would it work?  when would the namespace change?  Would it check everytime the service was invoked?  I can only see something working when the service is re-started when maybe you could read something from a db, but this is still not changing at runtime only refreshing at startup.  Your current procedure is not changing at runtime, so I'm not sure why that is a requirement now.

Comment: You do have a point Sam!  I don't think this is poosible to populate from db dring runtime.  I just don't like it part of the build process.

Comment: could you read it from a config file when you start up?  Would that help?

Comment: They don't want to put these tokens in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any other than using Conditional Compilation Symbols, i.e.

```
#if Debug 
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "@AA.BBB@/", Name = "FedExContract")]

#endif
```

Namespaces are meant to be static as you might need to recreate your client proxy if you change the namespace of the contract.

Comment: May be this is the only option left.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it during runtime. But it would be a lot of work and it would have to happen before the service started. Once the service starts you can't modify contract information.

Personally I don't like a service start that that's dependent on the DB. If something breaks, the service never comes up and troubleshooting could be a complicated process for IT. If I was to go the runtime route I would store the namespace value in my config file. Just keeps it simple, and still enables a post deploy token replace like what you describe in your question.

From the comments you mention build process. This is how we handle it: Make the namespace a constant string. So for example:

```
[DataContract(Namespace=Constants.CURRENT_NAMESPACE]
public class MyClass
{ }
```

Now in a separate file declare:

```
// in a separate file define:
public static class Constants
{
    public const string CURRENT_NAMESPACE = "url://Services";
};
```

When you want to build for a different environment swap out the Constants file for a new definition:

```
//As a part of your build process switch the Constants file:
public static class Constants
{
    public const string CURRENT_NAMESPACE = "url://Eclipse/Services";
};
```

Its easy to manage, you always know what namespace is being used... and the service always starts. Does that work?

Comment: We do something similar.  Is there a way this can be done from MS Build instead of using Eclipse/Ant?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I'm not the right person to ask. Might be a good second question to post.